# Symfony2 test on ajax form

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

In a symfony2 application I'm trying to test a form which has dropdown lists which are added dynamically (depending on previous dropdown lists selection).

Basically my problem is that I can't set the value for the dropdown list which I need to save in database as the crawler won't see it.

Does anybody know how I'm supposed to do this? Maybe somehow create the form element 'dropdown list' in the test and set its value?

Here's my code:

```
    // Fill lesson create form
    $form = $crawler->selectButton('submit')->form();
    $lesson_name = 'Lesson_Test_'.time();
    $form['LessonDetailForm[name]'] = $lesson_name;
    $form['LessonDetailForm[description]'] = 'This is a test lesson.';
    $form['LessonDetailForm[text]'] = 'The content of this lesson is quite short.';
    // This worked on a non-dynamic dropdown list :
    //$availableOptionValues = $form['LessonDetailForm[topic]']->availableOptionValues();
    //$form['LessonDetailForm[topic]']->select($availableOptionValues[1]);
    //$form['LessonDetailForm[topic]'] = 1;

    // Here I would like to build the dropdown list myself:
    $form['LessonDetailForm[topic]'] = new Form(...);
    $crawler = self::$client->submit($form);
```

I was also considering modifying the form especially for the test, with a possibility to somehow not post the value for this dropdown list. But that seems like a bad practice.

Comment: can you show some code samples of what you have tried?

Answer (score 0):

Your code does not appear to an AJAX Symfony2 Code. Have you the complete function in your Controller ?
Do you know this :

if( $request->isXmlHttpRequest() )

Comment: I think you totaly missed my point. This is the code of the test.